# Chrome Notifications Using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome

On page load I request the user to allow notifications like so:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
        Notification.requestPermission();
});
```

I have then wrote a function to send notifications to the user which works fine:

```
function push(title, message, location) {
    if(!Notification) { return; }
    if (Notification.permission !== "granted") { return; }
    var notification = new Notification(title, {
        icon: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png',
        body: message,
    });
    notification.onclick = function () {
      window.open(location);      
    };
}
```

Used like this:

```
push('Test', 'Test Message', 'http://example.com');
```

I then have a PHP script, for the time being it is static and returns the same thing for testing soon to be database driven.

```
session_start();
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
if(!isset($_SESSION['notify'])) {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'Title' => 'Welcome to our Site',
        'Message' => 'You are current recieving notifications.',
        'Location' => 'http://example.com/',
        'State' => true
    ),true);
    $_SESSION['notify'] = true;
} else {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'State' => false
    ), true);
}
```

This works fine too when the page is directly accessed. The issue occurs in my AJAX request:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.post('../notify/get_notify.php').done(function(response) {
            if(response.State) {
                push(response.Title, response.Message, response.Location);
            }
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
}, 5000);
```

The issue is here! When I check the network, every 5 seconds a request is being made and the response is coming back. However, nothing is logged in the console and the `push()` method is not executed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, due to the scope of the `$.post()` I was unable to retrieve anything, so instead I returned the value of the response like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        response = $.post('../notify/get_notify.php').done(function(response) {
            return response;
        });
        if(response.State) {
            push(response.Title, response.Message, response.Location);
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```